# Without looking in either direction - why not "neither"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, differences

In a book I read to improve my English, I ran across the following sentence (simplified):

> ..across the street, without looking in either direction.

I know "either" is often used when there is a choice with 2 options. But in this context, if he did not look either left or right, then he did not look in neither direction..at least that is how I understand it.

I struggle to understand why "either" is used here.
And, how would the following change the meaning, please?

> - ..without looking in neither direction.
> - ..without looking in both directions.

Comment: Because you are using without.

Comment: @user067531 Hmm, that is a good point, so that switches the context into a negative one?

Comment: Without looking in either direction = Looking in neither direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  the  comments  rightly pointed  out,

> **Without  looking in  either  direction**  means   looking  in  neither  direction.  Here  there  is  some  choice  , you  need  not  look  in  this  direction or  in  that  direction.
>
> **Without  looking in  both  directions**  means you  need not  look in both  the  directions. It  may  imply  that  you  may  look  in  one  direction

Here  is  a  link  which  shows  the use of  *both*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/both